# How do I add the copyright symbol to my webpage?

Tags: html

How do I add the copyright symbol to my webpage?

Answer (score 31):

Use `&copy;` in your HTML and you get ©.

Answer (score 8):

Use `&#169;` or `&copy;`  The last one is easier to remember. Disadvantage is that some exotic browser can't read it, so then you have to use the number.

Answer (score 5):

You type the character ©. The way you do that depends on your authoring environment. Using Windows, for example, you can use `Alt+0169` if you cannot find a more convenient way.

You need to make sure that the character encoding of the page is properly declared, but you should do that anyway.

Even if you are using a legacy encoding like *windows-1252* or *iso-8859-1* and not the modern *UTF-8*, the copyright sign © can be entered as such.

Comment: Hmm - why the downvotes, this is a perfectly valid answer. If you look at the unicode table, the copyright belongs to the Latin-1 table and that means, there should be no problem with using the character directly.

Comment: Yes this is at least equally as good an answer as the others.

Comment: I downvoted because if you use html 5 © displays as a ?.  But &copy; displays as expected.
!DOCTYPE html>
html>

Comment: @Guy Thomas, then your character encoding is wrong, or it has not been declared properly. It is useful to know this from a character about which you know how it should look like. One more reason for using the character itself.

Comment: @Guy Thomas - I was pretty sure that's not a problem of HTML5, but because of your comment i tested it out. I tested with different encodings `utf-8`, `windows-1252` and `iso-8859-1` und tried it with different browsers just back to IE6. It always displayed correctly (all test pages where validated before). Can you provide an example of a non working page, so we could have a look at the source?

Comment: I have learned a great deal from this.  Here is my page.  http://www.guy-sports.com/funny/funny_science_jokesa.htm While this page produces the problem, it is due to mal-formed utf-8 meta tag, which I must research.  Thus I have reversed my down vote.

Comment: @Guy Thomas, the meta tag is OK. But the document is not really utf-8 encoded. If you manually force the browser to interpret the document as iso-8859-1 encoded (via the View > Encoding command), you will see that “©” appears—because the document is in fact in iso-8859-1 or compatible encoding (like “ANSI”, or windows-1252). That is, you probably saved in that encoding, but the meta tag says otherwise.

Comment: @Guy Thomas - Additionally to the declaration with the utf-8 tag, the file format itself has to be utf-8 (can use 1-4 Bytes per character). Most editors today are capable of storing in this format (even notepad). I had a look at your page with a HEX-Editor and it seems not to be stored as utf-8.

Comment: Thank you both.  At last I see MY problem in Web Expression.  Could I do a search for meta charset=utf-8
 and replace with: meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"?

Comment: @Guy Thomas - That's not the solution. Instead you should tell Web-Expression that it should save the file utf-8 encoded. Unfortunately i don't know Web-Expression, but i found a [link](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/tips/expressionweb.html#encoding) with a screenshot that could be helpful for you.

Comment: Screenshot helpful.  I joined the Web Expression forum, they were able to confirm that my above find and replace is the equivelent of the GUI.  I'll sign of by saying meeting you good people online, not only helped solved a problem I did not know I had, but generally cheered me up.

Comment: @Guy Thomas - You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Use `&copy;` or `&#169;`.

Here's a complete reference of HTML symbol/sign: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm.

Comment: Please don't just repeat other already said. It's not relevant because the question owner  already got this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get a copyright symbol into your web page:

- Copy and paste it in: `©` (assuming your editor and web server agree on the character set (like `UTF-8`))
- Use the HTML named entity `&copy;`
- Use the numeric entity `&#160;`
- Type it using  `<Alt>0169` (also assumes your editor and web server can support extended characters properly)

Comment: Please don't simply reiterate over other answers. The individual solutions can be upvoted already, we don't need one answer to rule them all that is simply taken from other answers

Comment: No other answer suggested copy and pasting it verbatim. I wrote this answer mainly to provide that alternative -- as I usually find it to be the best option.  It wouldn't be a complete answer without all the possibilities.

Comment: `<kbd>ALT</kbd>0169` (or copy-paste) may display as intended, *even when producing invalid HTML code*. Browsers often render pages as intended, even when code is invalid or full of errors. Also, these methods make the text non-portable: changing servers could break the copyright notice. So, it's not recommended as a "best" option. It'd be helpful to add a reference on how a user can check if their web server supports extended characters. It *is* handy to be aware of the copy-paste method in a pinch (or for text documents), and of alt-`0169` in case related errors are encountered in the wild.